# Inserting string data into varchar column causes invalid cast to int

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've run into a strange situation with SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a large table with too many columns (over 100). Two of the columns are defined as varchar, but inserting text data into these columns via an INSERT-VALUES statement generates an invalid cast exception.

```sql
CREATE TABLE TooManyColumns (
    ...
    , column_A varchar(20)
    , column_B varchar(10)
    , ...
)

INSERT INTO TooManyColumns (..., column_A, column_B, ...)
    VALUES (..., 'text-A1', 'text-B1', ...)
        , (..., 'text-A2', 'text-B2', ...)
```

Results in these errors

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'text-A1' to data type int.
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'text-B1' to data type int.
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'text-A2' to data type int.
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'text-B2' to data type int.
```

I've verified the position of the values against the position of the columns. Further, changing the text values into numbers or into text implicitly convertible to numbers, fixes the error and inserts the numeric values into the expected columns.

What should I look for to trouble shoot this?

I've already looked for constraints on the two columns but could not find any - so either I'm looking in the wrong place or they do not exist. The SSMS object explorer states that the two columns are defined as `varchar(20)` and `varchar(10)`. Using SSMS tools to script the table's schema to a query window also confirms this.

Anything else I should check?

Comment: Check the order of columns in insert statement

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri As stated, I already checked. Changing the data to conform to an INT successfully inserts the numeric data in the expected columns - but the columns are `varchar` and should accept text data as well.

Comment: Then check for triggers. May be the trigger is problem

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: I see no triggers via the SSMS object explorer. That node has no children. The table has 5 constraints - but all are Default Value constraints, on other columns. There are many PK-FK relations on the table, but they all reference other columns. Likewise with indices, though maybe some of the indices have one or both of these columns as additional, non-key data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is 'What should I look for to trouble shoot this?'  So this answers that question, it does not necessarily solve your problem.

I would do this:

```
 select * into TooManyColumns_2 from 
TooManyColumns

truncate table TooManyColumns

update TooManyColumns_2
set --your troubled columns with text data that is not convetable to int


insert TooManyColumns select * from TooManyColumns_2
```

If the insert select is successful then the problem is likely your column ordering on your inserts, because this proves that these columns can take text data.  If that fails, then report back for further troubleshooting tips.

Comment: Due to the large size of the subject table and that my teammates may be using it, I attempted to replicate the problem in two other copies of the database. However, the problem does not occur in either of them. I'm wondering if we have a corrupted database file...

Comment: I don't know what happened, but the problem has disappeared. I guess it was some sort of transient (though at least 18 hours) issue that was corrected by SQL Server's built-in maintenance routines.